# How to return a existing document except an element using xquery in marklogic

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I have a document I have written to ignore the element id from the document and return the document as below but throws error

```
let $ex := fn:doc("/name/docs")/* except $ex//sar:id return $ex
```

returns

> Error: **undefined variable $ex**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to reference the `let` variable within the `let` statement. You can't do that.

You could `let` a variable for the document, and then use it in a similar statement:

```
let $doc := fn:doc("/name/docs")
let $ex := $doc/* except $doc//sar:id 
return $ex
```

Or you could use a simple mapping operator:

```
let $ex := fn:doc("/name/docs") ! (./* except .//sar:id) 
return $ex
```

That will return a sequence of child elements from the document (but there is only one immediate child element for a doc, so unless it happens to be `sar:id`, [that likely won't achieve what you are trying to do](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69367918/14419).

If you want to return a new document that has all of the content except for the `sar:id` element, then you could run it through an XSLT that is a modified identity transform with an empty template matching that element to exclude:

```
declare variable $XSLT := 
  <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:sar="sar-namespace-needs-to-be-updated-here">
    <!--this generic template matches on, and copies all attributes and nodes by default-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <!--this empty template will ensure that the sar:id is dropped from the output-->
    <xsl:template match="sar:id"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>;

xdmp:xslt-eval($XSLT, fn:doc("/name/docs"))
```

Otherwise you could run it through a recursive descent function with a typeswitch. I find XSLT shorter and easier to write, but that's a personal preference.

Comment: I updated that first, had a syntax error of my own! But like I said, from what I *think* you are trying to do, it may not do what you want. If you want to return a new document that excludes that element, the XSLT is the easier way. I can also add a pure XQuery solution if you'd like.